# Is there any method to find the end of word docx file using python

Tags: python, xml, page-break

I got stucked at one position, where i need to find the end of a word document using python. i have tried many combination like XML parser to find a particular tag(W:type) but didn't work. So guys please help with your solutions or any ideas to solve this ticket.

Sample format

doc file structure as follows

1.docx

[Header]

Body
..
.
.
.
.
.

[body ends]

[page ends] // I need to find this point using python

---

Comment: what have you tried so far? And provide an example.

Comment: I have tried in minding the embedded XML tag(w:type), so if i could find it then i cant display a message saying that the particular point the end of that page. But still couldn't get the find a way to achieve that.........

Comment: The main problem is, I am not even getting any thread like how pdf are doing it, because when we convert a doc to pdf, it simply finds the end of the page and will put a number at footer

Answer (score 0):

Use [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
from docx import Document

document = Document('<your_docx_path>')

for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    if '<text_you_want_to_find>' in paragraph.text:
        // find point
```

Comment: thank you for your reply,

But i have to do this with every single docx file, so i hope this wont work. (for each uploaded file)